SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when accessing openai api
I recently came across this error when trying to use openai api.
ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)
I do not understand, I never had this problem before and was using openai without hiccups.
I do not remember installing/uninstalling anything on my machine. I have pretty much exhausted every solution presented on the internet to no avail.
I also ended up doing uninstall/reinstall of anaconda, still no success.
I am using macOS Sonoma - version 14.5
I would like to request if anyone has resolve this error:
Below is the error message:
ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py:952, in SyncAPIClient._request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
    951 try:
--> 952     response = self._client.send(
    953         request,
    954         stream=stream or self._should_stream_response_body(request=request),
    955         **kwargs,
    956     )
    957 except httpx.TimeoutException as err:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:914, in Client.send(self, request, stream, auth, follow_redirects)
    912 auth = self._build_request_auth(request, auth)
--> 914 response = self._send_handling_auth(
    915     request,
    916     auth=auth,
    917     follow_redirects=follow_redirects,
    918     history=[],
    919 )
    920 try:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:942, in Client._send_handling_auth(self, request, auth, follow_redirects, history)
    941 while True:
--> 942     response = self._send_handling_redirects(
    943         request,
    944         follow_redirects=follow_redirects,
    945         history=history,
    946     )
    947     try:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:979, in Client._send_handling_redirects(self, request, follow_redirects, history)
    977     hook(request)
--> 979 response = self._send_single_request(request)
    980 try:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:1015, in Client._send_single_request(self, request)
   1014 with request_context(request=request):
-> 1015     response = transport.handle_request(request)
   1017 assert isinstance(response.stream, SyncByteStream)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py:232, in HTTPTransport.handle_request(self, request)
    220 req = httpcore.Request(
    221     method=request.method,
    222     url=httpcore.URL(
   (...)
    230     extensions=request.extensions,
    231 )
--> 232 with map_httpcore_exceptions():
    233     resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py:158, in _GeneratorContextManager.__exit__(self, typ, value, traceback)
    157 try:
--> 158     self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
    159 except StopIteration as exc:
    160     # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that
    161     # was passed to throw().  This prevents a StopIteration
    162     # raised inside the "with" statement from being suppressed.

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py:86, in map_httpcore_exceptions()
     85 message = str(exc)
---> 86 raise mapped_exc(message) from exc


Try executing /Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command.

Already did this, and no success at all!

As it states, you have self signed certificate. Try to get it and place it local on your machine.
from openai import OpenAI
import httpx
http_client = httpx.Client(verify="path/to/your/ca")

client = OpenAI(
    ...,
    http_client = http_client,
    ...
) 

It should work

had to disable my netskope altogether to make it work
